# to show an error message while entering duplicates when column is primary key

Tags: c#

As in table named Emp i have Name Column is Primary key,when i add duplicate name like (Bharat Mali) which is already present in database,this record is not get added in database,but showing me this message( employee added successfully) i want to show a message to user like(duplicate values can't be stored).
 I am using this code behind Add button Click

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBHandling db = new DBHandling();
            if (name.Text.Trim().Equals("")&& name.Text.Trim().Equals("select Emp.name from Emp"))
            {
                name.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be blank or same!");
            }
            else if(Payment.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                Payment.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Payment cannot be blank!");
            }
            else if (!IsNumeric(Payment.Text.Trim()))
            {
                Payment.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Payment should contain Numerical Values!");
            }
                else if(CellNumber.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                CellNumber.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Cell Number cannot be blank!");

            }
            else if (!IsNumeric(CellNumber.Text.Trim()) || CellNumber.Text.Trim().Length<10)
            {
                CellNumber.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Cell Number!");
            }
            else if(JoiningDate.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                JoiningDate.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("set Joining Date!");
            }             
            else
            {
                db.AddEmp(name.Text, Payment.Text, CellNumber.Text, Education.Text, JoiningDate.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Employee added successfully!");
            }
            name.Clear();           
            Payment.Clear();           
            CellNumber.Clear();            
            Education.Clear();
            name.Focus();

        }
```

so how should i do it ,thanks .

I am checking PK using this below line of code ,I am not getting any answer for this but not even an error,do you know any other way that how should i do it?

```
if (name.Text.Trim().Equals("")&& name.Text.Trim().Equals("select Emp.name from Emp"))
                {
                    name.Focus();
                    MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be blank or same!");
                }
```

Comment: Did you try to catch the exception thrown by `db.AddEmp` method or the return value?

Comment: You should be getting an error from the underlying database. Make db.AddEmp a function and return the error code or a boolean stating it was succesfull. It would be helpful to see the code for db.AddEmp.

Answer (score 2):

Exception ways of writing code is not good. It deteriorates the performance of the application. Rather, check if the PK value is already existing in the DB. May be to even make it faster you could have an internal data structure of PKs only and check there first and then if its not there, update that plus DB

Comment: if (name.Text.Trim().Equals("")&& name.Text.Trim().Equals("select Emp.name from Emp"))
            {
                name.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be blank or same!");
            }                                                                    I am cheking PK using this line of code ,I am not getting any answer for this but not even an error,do you know any other way that how should i do it?

Comment: Please indent the code properly. Its difficult to read the code this way. May be you can use pastebin.com

Comment: I have edited this line of code at the end of my quetion ,pls go through it